# Overloading class for both volatile and non-volatile instances

Tags: c++, overloading, volatile

I am writing a class that needs to support both volatile and non-volatile instances (volatile instances use atomic operations, non-volatile instances use regular operations), and am wondering if I am going about it in the correct way. Here's a snippit of the class declaration so far:

```
class Yield {
public:
    Yield();
    Yield(Yield const &other);
    Yield(Yield const volatile &other);

    Yield &operator=(Yield const &other);
    Yield &operator=(Yield const volatile &other);

    Yield &operator+=(Yield const &other);
    Yield &operator+=(Yield const volatile &other);
    Yield volatile &operator+=(Yield const &other) volatile;
    Yield volatile &operator+=(Yield const volatile &other) volatile;

    // Other operators snipped...
};
```

- Question 1: When compiling with MSVC, I get the following warning:

  `warning C4521: 'util::Yield' : multiple copy constructors specified`

  Does this warning portend any problems in using this class? Or can it be safely ignored?
- Question 2: As it stands, all operators are overloaded for both a volatile and non-volatile `other` argument. I assume this is necessary in order to avoid slower volatile accesses for non-volatile instances? Is there an alternative to allow each method to be coded only twice (volatile lhs and non-volatile lhs) rather than 4 times (volatile and non-volatile lhs, each with volatile and non-volatile rhs)?

I hope putting these questions together is ok, otherwise please leave a comment and I can split them.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Volatile does not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866206/volatile-and-createthread/6866927#6866927).

Even with VC++'s special, non-standard `volatile` behavior, it results in slower code than writing it properly.  Use `std::atomic`, or if that's not available then you've probably got platform-specific barrier, fence, and atomic intrinsics. VC++ has `_ReadWriteBarrier` and `_Interlocked` functions to help you.

Comment: Yup, I am aware that volatile doesn't automagically provide safe multithreading, I just want to use it to distinguish between needing atomic operations (when the instance is shared) and when not (the instance is only used locally). It would be nice not to have to replicate the code multiple times, but so far other variations e.g. using templates have been even uglier.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't provide any multithreading benfits, nor any atomicity. Consider naming your functions _atomic or something similar instead of using a `volatile` `this`, so that people reading your code can tell what it does.

Answer (score 3):

> The class has multiple copy constructors of a single type. This warning is informational; the constructors are callable in your program.

From the msdn website: [Compiler Warning (level 3) C4521](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e02fwk4s.aspx)

Comment: I editted your answer to provide the part I think you meant would answer his question. Next time its better to provide the part which would answer the question than just linking to a website.