# GCC atomic builtins and volatile

Tags: gcc, thread-safety, volatile, atomicreference

I use some global structures in a multithreaded program, some of the members are modified by multiple threads simultaneously, some others are not.

I didn't define any of this members volatile, but anytime i use this members for both reading and writing purposes, i use atomic builtins such as __sync_fetch_and_add.

The question is, should i define this members or the whole struct volatile?

I think the compiler has to access the memory instead any register because of this builtins (lock prefix), should i be worried about other members that are not cause race conditions.

I checked out the assembly output of my compiler (gcc 4.6.2) and it seems my assumption is right.

Here is the test code.

```
int sum = 0;

for (i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

The assembly output (-O2 -S -masm=intel)

```
L2:
    add edx, eax
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 2000000000
    jne L2
```

So compiler is never accessed the memory (eax = i, edx = sum)

Here is the second test code.

```
volatile int sum = 0;

for (i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
    sum += i;
}
```

The assembly output

```
L2:
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+28]
    add edx, eax
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], edx
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 2000000000
    jne L2
```

Compiler accessed the memory for sum everytime as expected.

The final code, my way.

```
int sum = 0;

for (i=0; i<2000000000; i++) {
    __sync_fetch_and_add(&sum , i);
}
```

The assembly output.

```
L2:
    lock add    DWORD PTR [esp+28], eax
    inc eax
    cmp eax, 2000000000
    jne L2
```

Not even a temp register as before (edx), compiler accessed the memory everytime.

So, i don't define volatile any member that modified by multiple threads or modified by only one thread at a time. Am i safe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Volatile is best avoided in most cases -- it doesn't have anything to do with multi-threading. Use explicit barriers instead.

Comment: I think it does. If i use a global variable in a loop at thread1 and compiler uses a register instead of memory access as i show, thread2 can modify this variable in memory and the result is mess.

Comment: It absolutely doesn't! [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866206/volatile-and-createthread/6866927#6866927) for an explanation. Note, GCC's _sync functions operate as a barrier themselves.

Comment: I think you didnt understand my previous comment. Read this article written by Andrei Alexandrescu. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766 so it says, Although both C and C++ Standards are conspicuously silent when it comes to threads, they do make a little concession to multithreading, in the form of the volatile keyword.

Comment: C11 has lots of new threading features.  It's definitely not silent on the issue!

Comment: That's right, actually it's going to be better, there is a study group (SG1) works on concurrency and the next minor standart is coming (2014). But my question is on C. I give this article to convince Nelson that volatile has something to do with multithreading. Even though the code that i modify global variable is thread safe (by mutex or something), compiler can change the register instead of the memory, and another thread can read a different value from memory of this variable. Volatile is important in that case. But since __sync functions are always modify the memory, i am safe.

Comment: Respect to Andrei, but that article was written during a time when very few understood standard `volatile`'s lack of usefulness for threading -- his first example (`Wakeup`) assuming non-standard VC++ behavior shows that he was likely as clueless as everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are safe. The documentation does not say they should be volatile, so they shouldn't.

The `__sync`* functions act as memory barriers as appropriate, so `volatile` would be superfluous. And it wouldn't allow using anything else beyond the `__sync`* functions anyway (only the `__sync`* functions generate the `lock` prefix).

Note: The `__sync`* functions are deprecated in gcc 4.7 in favour of C++11-style `__atomic`* types, but gcc 4.6 does not have those yet.

Comment: Then why __atomic in C++ expect the argument to be volatile type*? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_fetch_add